# Multiplication table in c by 'while'

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int j = 1;
    scanf_s("%d", &i);

    while (i < 10)
    {
        while (j < 10)
        {
            printf("%d * %d = %d \n", i, j, i*j);
            j++;
        }
        i++;

    }

}
```

In this program, when I give the program variable 'i' to 3, this program only print 3*1 ~ 3*9
Why isn't i be 4~9? When using 'while', is 'i' a local variable?

Please somebody explain why this situation is appear.
(I'm south korean, not good at english. Sorry.)

Comment: `When using 'while', is 'i' a local variable?` -- No, because you didn't declare it inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Welcome!  Observationally, looks like `i` hasn't been initialized.

Comment: @slightlynybbled: `i` gets initialized at the `scanf_s` call.

Comment: Got it.  I'm a microcontroller guy :)

Answer (score 1):

You must re-set `j` to 1 inside the outer loop, otherwise it's never going to go back down to 1.

```
while (i < 10)
{
    while (j < 10)
    {
        printf("%d * %d = %d \n", i, j, i*j);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

obviously (?) a `for` loop is more suitable here:

```
while (i < 10)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; ++j)
    {
        printf("%d * %d = %d\n", i, j, i * j);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much.  :) you are genius

Comment: @YujinSon Thanks! Experience helps, it really does. :)

Answer (score 1):

You forget to update the program variable 'j' during while loop.
So you can change your program code like :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int j = 1;
    scanf_s("%d", &i);

    while (i < 10)
    {
        j = 1;
        while (j < 10)
        {
            printf("%d * %d = %d \n", i, j, i*j);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

}
```